# A butterfly-shaped text box

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I'm working with beamer and I would like to create a fly-shaped colored text box [like in the cover of the tcolorbox manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

The first page of the manual actually features the code for that cover page but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I would like to have a slide fully occupied by the insect-shaped 4-boxes figure, in which boxes I would like to be able to write.

**Bonus** I would like the 4 text boxes to have this color settings

> colback=myred!5!white,colframe=myred!75!black

and the body and antennas to be colored of the same myred color

> \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{87,24,32}

Comment: can you provide your code? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: It's an error with the beamer environment, I guess. It stops and the \end{frame} command.
Even if I write a MWE with just a plain slide and that code in it (that basically is want I want) it won't compile.

Comment: Probabily it's necessary to strip all the part about the background etc. but I just can't understand how...

Comment: can you provide the MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{most,documentation}
\definecolor{Green_Dark}{rgb}{0.078431,0.407843,0.176471}
\definecolor{Blue_Dark}{rgb}{0.090196,0.211765,0.364706}
\definecolor{Blue_Bright}{rgb}{0.858824,0.898039,0.945098}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, transform canvas={scale=0.6, xshift=6cm,yshift=-1cm}]
\definecolorseries{boxcol}{rgb}{last}{blue}{red}
\resetcolorseries[28]{boxcol}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (current page.center);
\path[use as bounding box] (A) rectangle coordinate (C) (B);
\node at (C) {%
  \begin{tcbitemize}[title=tcolorbox xx,fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
    enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0.5,opacitybacktitle=0.75,
    halign=center,valign=center,arc=5mm,
    raster width=16cm,raster column skip=8mm,raster halign=center,
    raster force size=false,
    raster row 1/.style={height=6cm},
    raster row 2/.style={width=6cm,height=4cm},
    raster column 1/.style={flushright title,
      frame style={left color=yellow!50!black,right color=green!50!black},
      title style={left color=yellow!50!blue,right color=blue!50!green!50!black},
      interior style={left color=yellow!70,right color=green!70},
      underlay={\draw[line width=6mm,line cap=round,black!60]
        ([shift={(0.4,-0.15)}]frame.north east)
        --([shift={(0.4,0.15)}]frame.south east); }},
    raster column 2/.style={
      frame style={left color=green!50!black,right color=yellow!50!black},
      title style={left color=blue!50!green!50!black,right color=yellow!50!blue},
      interior style={left color=green!70,right color=yellow!70}}]
  \tcbitem[fontupper=\Huge\bfseries,sharp corners=east,
    underlay={\draw[line width=6mm,line cap=round,black!60]
      ([shift={(0.4,0.30)}]frame.north east)-- coordinate(A) +(0,0.2);
      \draw[line width=1mm,line cap=round,black!60](A) -- +(30:1.5cm);
      \draw[line width=1mm,line cap=round,black!60](A) -- +(150:1.5cm);}]
    tcolorbox
  \tcbitem[fontupper=\large\bfseries,sharp corners=west]
    Manual for\\ version\\ xx\\(xx)
  \tcbitem[sharp corners=northeast]
  \tcbitem[sharp corners=northwest] Thomas F.~Sturm
  \end{tcbitemize}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much :)
Any chance that can be edited to be in "myred" palette?

Comment: @luciadefinetti search for `yellow` and `green` in the code and change them